# How to use Set-Cookie header attribute

Tags: cookies, setcookie

I have a client-server application, and I'm trying to set the access and refresh tokens as cookies in the browser. I set the response headers on the server side and the response looks like this:
[image]

**The cookies are not set in the browser.** I've read most of the posts about this issue, I've changed the SameSite to Lax and then to None (yes, I've added the Secure attribute when I've set it to None) but it didn't work. I've added and removed the HttpOnly, but that did not work either. I've runed out ideeas so if you have any please let me know.
A better view of the cookies:
[image]

I'm using Mozilla/5.0 Firefox/98.0.